# Spree on shipment_state change callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, solidus

I want to run some code when shipment state changes to "shipped". I saw that there is the state_machine for order state change callbacks:
`state_machine.after_transition to: :complete, do: :do_something`
I wonder if there is something similar for shipment state and if not, what would be the best approach to detect and react to that change?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the same approach for shipments using something like:

```rb
after_transition to: :shipped, do: :do_something
```